# Why free style job jenkins faster than jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I create two jobs. First with freestyle job and second with pipeline.

First job takes 35-41 sec.
Second job takes 55 - 69 sec.

I use Jenkins version latest LTS in docker.
In both jobs I run the same script. (Ansible -> docker)

Why jenkins pipeline is slow?

Comment: What about some log output?

Comment: what is the job flow , can you add the output with timestamp of both jobs ?

Comment: @element were you be able to solve / find root cause?